# Mongodb query object without field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm trying to query a full mongodb field but without an intern field, like this document example:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('x8234728x8z8381'),
  Example: {
       field1: 'first',
       field2: 'second',
       field3: {
          field 3.1: 'third'
       }
  }
}
```

[image]

I would like to return all "Example" field, but without "$field2". Is it possible in mongodb?

Comment: Ouch!  You named your fields with a `$`?  It's doable, but why use `$` and then have to worry about possible consequences?

Comment: It was just an example to mock my real data hahaha, when I put this data I didn't pay attention to it ahahah

Comment: It's also better not to use images for code/errors/back traces/stack traces/etc.  If you put them in a code block, it's easier for us to copy/paste.  Code images are like answer repellent.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$project": {
    "Example.field2": 0
  }
})
```

You just ignore it in projection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` and then just not "project" the fields you want to eliminate.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "_id": ObjectId("62a6144faf59381072fa83d6")
},
{
  "Example.field2": false
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wQYVGoqD6jI).